# Generating a symmetric key in php

Tags: php, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, symmetric-key

Im trying to generate a symmetric key, which i can use to both encrypt and decrypt a message with the same key, in php.

I've made my way through the php documentation below but can only find public/private key generations:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php

Any ideas on how i can use these key generating functions for making a symmetric key?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: There are special functions for generating public/private keypairs because the two keys have a special mathematical relationship to each other, but a symmetric key is ideally just a random number with no mathematical relationship to anything.  So you want to look at functions for generating cryptographic-quality random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *symetric* key is basically a random set of bytes. If you want to use the `openssl` extension use [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes):

```
$symetric_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a symmetric key you can either use [`random_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) (starting from PHP 7) or [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes). Using the OpenSSL extension to crypt data with a symmetric key, you can use [`openssl_cipher_key_length()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-key-length.php) to know the required key length.

```php
$cipher = "aes-256-gcm";
$plaintext = "Attack at dawn!";

if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher));
  $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_key_length($cipher));
  $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
}
```